# PHP/SQL StoringThe Name Of The Currently Logged In User Upon Form Completion

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

Once users are logged into my website, they can fill out a form which has two fields, "project name" and "project description".

I need help storing the username of the person who filled that form out.

For example, if I was to be logged in as Admin and filled the form out, in the database it should show the username Admin next to the form information.

Help is much appreciated and thank you in advance!

The form DB:
Database name: formsystem
Table name: form
Column I want to save the usernames to: form_user

My Code (groupForm.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/form.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <nav>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div id="branding">
        <li><h1><span><a href="homepage.php">ProjectNet</a></span></li>
        </div>
            <div class="nav-login">
                <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                        echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                              <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                              </form>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST"> 
                              <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/Email">
                              <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                              <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                              </form>
                              <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>';
                    }
                ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="showcase1">
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="includes/form_process.php" method="POST">
    <h3>Creating a Group</h3>
    <h4>Please fill out the sections below.</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Project title" type="text" name="name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Description of the project...." type="text" name="message" ></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Create</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
</section>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Backend Code (form_process.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    function fetch_user_info($u_id){
    $u_id = (int)$u_id;

    $sql = "SELECT `user_uid` AS `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = {$u_id}";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

    include_once 'formDatabaseConnection.php';

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);

    //Check for empty fields
    if (empty($name) || empty($message)) {
        header("Location: ../groupForm.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        //Insert the user into the database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO form (form_user, form_name, form_description) VALUES ('$u_id', '$name', '$message');";

                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../findGroup.php");
                exit();
    }


} else {
    header("Location: ../groupForm.php");
    exit();
}
```

UPDATES:
Login code(login.inc.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    //Error handlers
    //Check if inputs are empty
    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //De-hashing the password
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    //log in the user here
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];

                    header("Location: ../homepage.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query` and `mysqli_query`. Use `mysqli_query` everywhere. Also use parameterized queries.

Comment: `$u_id` is not set at the point where you're referencing it in the INSERT.

Comment: You can store the username in the session the same way you're storing the `u_id`. Or you can make a separate query and get the username by that id.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for the suggestion, I am aware of the depreciated code and will get it fixed soon! :)

Comment: @KirillSimin I'm a beginner with all this, would you be able to help me with the syntax for it please?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Would you know how to set it correctly?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this, please? I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user logging in your system, store that user's ID & user name in session & retrieve that user name when you want to save it & replace your form_user value with that session value. Check below code for more clarification.

```
$username = $_SESSION['u_first']. ' '.$_SESSION['u_last'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO form (form_user, form_name, form_description) VALUES ($username, $name, $message)";
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on how to do that dude. I've updated my post above to include my login code also. Would you possibly provide me with some help on how to code it? I'm stuck on this one, been at it for days (I'm a beginner)

Comment: you have almost done it, don't worry. check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much dude, really appreciate the help. Your code did not work at first, but after logging out of the website and logging back in to submit a new form it worked! :D